# I want to change my game name. Is it possible?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to write my true name, but how can I do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure when you select your username, it clearly says "You cannot change this later."

Comment: your villagers wouldn't know where they live...

Comment: Well now your villagers are equipped with GPS to find your new village ;)

Answer (score 10):

Its official now, as part of the Air sweeper defense update, players who have town hall 5 and above have the ability to change the name once.

> To change the name, go to settings and click on *Change name*.

You will be able to do it only once, so choose wisely :)

Reference: http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/641277-UPDATE-30-04-Air-Sweeper

Comment: More information on this posted by Anoushka[Supercell] on the CoC forums: "Only one (1) name change per player will be allowed (and it is for free); as many people suggested already, each player will have its unique player tag (found in player profile), just like clan tags, except that there won't be any "player search" tab or feature."

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I have added it, and also included link to the original thread.

Comment: It official now, update is out. Edited links for the official announcement thread in forum.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Supercell's faq](http://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&l=en&s=hot-topics&f=can-i-change-my-village-s-name), you may not change your name once you make one.

You can try contacting Support at clashofclans.feedback@supercell.com.

However they typically only change it if:
 - Your full name is exposed, or
 - It contains offensive words.

Edit:
According to notes about an upcoming update, you will be able to change your name once, for free, in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Adding depth into @Goodsp33d's Answer

1. Click the Settings button (The Gears on the right side of the screen)
2. Click "Change Name"
3. Enter New Name.
4. Regret that you forgot to use Capitalization
5. Get Over It
6. Go Drink a 2 Liter of Mtn Dew, or Dr.Pepper ... You're choice

You're Welcome :)